# Change the assigned function and text to a button in a WPF Datagrid depending on column value

Tags: c#, wpf, datagrid

I have this button inside a column:

```
<DataGridTemplateColumn>
       <DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
              <DataTemplate>
                     <Button Click="UpdateTopic">Update</Button>
              </DataTemplate>
       </DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
</DataGridTemplateColumn>
```

But now I require that both the text in it and the function applied to it to change according to the value in one of my column. How can I achieve this?

Comment: use `binding` to change text and check the value of your column within the function (or use `binding` too)..

Comment: You cannot bind functions, apparently.

Answer (score 0):

Create a property in your code behind or view model and bind it to the `Button.Content` property:

```
<Button Click="UpdateTopic" Content={Binding ButtonText}" />
```

Assuming that you have access to your data objects bound to the `DataGrid` as the column value changes, edit the method in your code behind that is linked to the `Button.Click` event to something like this:

```
public void UpdateTopic()
{
    if (columnValue == "Something") DoSomething();
    else if (columnValue == "SomethingElse") DoSomethingElse();
    else if (columnValue == "AnotherThing") DoAnotherThing();
}
```

This way, you can have one click handler that performs a variety of duties dependant on the current value of the column.